# Local host WordPress theme are broken due to port issue

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, localhost

I'm using 'MAMP for windows' to install and develop wordPress in my Local Windows 10 machine. The port which my Apache is listening to is localhost:8888. I'm successfully able to install WordPress in my local machine and login to my dashboard.

As you can observe from the below 3 screenshot. All my theme images and CSS are broken. The reason I found out(and highlighted) is that the all my theme related files are not taking the port address and it is referring to `localhost`, instead of `localhost:8888/`

I have my httpd.conf listening to localhost:8888

I've my Git configured with Openshift and hence my theme and plugin folders are moved from WordPress folder to .openshift folder. My wp-config is updated to reflect the same.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Please throw some lights on this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Finally got this issue resolved and saved a lot of time.

I just have to append the port number to the http server in the wp-config.php file.

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':8888/folder' );
```

Thanks to my friend Amit for helping me out.